# ArcGIS Portal Authentication Problem

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have a simple task to connecting to an ArcGIS Portal  (not AGOL) layer and querying the data for use in a console application. When the code attempts to instantiate LoadAsync() on the 'FeatureLayer' instance, he "ChallengeHandler" method is called. I supply my Windows/network credentials in the challenge handler. The ChallengeHandler is called another 19 times before the LoadAsync() throws a "Token required" exception. I can navigate to this layer via browser just fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static async Task<Credential> CreateCredentialAsync(CredentialRequestInfo info)
{
    Credential c = new ArcGISNetworkCredential(info.ServiceUri, new System.Net.NetworkCredential(user, pw));       
    Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Security.AuthenticationManager.Current.AddCredential(c);
    return await Task.FromResult(c);
}
```

I noticed the InnerException is of type 'ArcGISWebException', and the Code = 499.

Comment: If you keep getting challenged again and again, it's because the credentials you provide aren't valid. Also you shouldn't add the credential to the credential manager - just return `c` and it'll get added (btw you can remove 'async' and the 'await' and just return Task.FromResult(c))
One more thing: If you're getting token required, are you sure it wants a network credential and not a token credential? Check the parameters on 'info'

Comment: The 'AuthenticationType' parameter is set to 'Token'. Is there a way to use user credentials? I don't understand the whole token mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning this instead:

```
TokenCredential userCredentials = await AuthenticationManager.Current.GenerateCredentialAsync(
          info.ServiceUri, user, pw, 
          info.GenerateTokenOptions).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Always check the AuthenticationType first to know which sort of credential is needed from the user (could also be network credential, proxy or PKI X502 certificate)

Comment: That worked. One thing to note (that caused a lot of confusion) is that the username was my full corporate email, not my network login username. My password was the same as my corporate network login however.